# Derive the Triple Angle Formula Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

**Derive the Triple Angle Formula using the stated proposition:**

[image: Details to Derive Triple Angle Formulas]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the [de Moivre's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula):

$$e^{i3\phi}=\cos3\phi+i\sin3\phi=(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi)^3=\cos^3\phi-i\sin^3\phi+3i\cos^2\phi\sin\phi-3\sin^2\phi\cos\phi$$

Identifying real and imaginary parts: $$\cos3\phi=\cos^3\phi-3\sin^2\phi\cos\phi$$
$$\sin3\phi=3\cos^2\phi\sin\phi-\sin^3\phi$$

Comment: Thanks, I had just done a general proof that didn't use de moivre's formula..